# When executing a compiled C/C++ file with below code using seccomp and execve, it is exiting with status code 159 and signal 31

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-calls, execve, seccomp

I'm trying to execute C/C++ code in a secure environment using Seccomp and Ececve. But, C/C++  code is not being executed while trying with this setup. Please look at the files.

`seccomp_rules.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <seccomp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "seccomp_rules.h"


int c_cpp_seccomp_rules(struct config *_config, bool allow_write_file)
{

    int syscalls_whitelist[] = {SCMP_SYS(read), SCMP_SYS(fstat),
                                SCMP_SYS(mmap), SCMP_SYS(mprotect),
                                SCMP_SYS(munmap), SCMP_SYS(uname),
                                SCMP_SYS(arch_prctl), SCMP_SYS(brk),
                                SCMP_SYS(access), SCMP_SYS(exit_group),
                                SCMP_SYS(close), SCMP_SYS(readlink),
                                SCMP_SYS(sysinfo), SCMP_SYS(write),
                                SCMP_SYS(writev), SCMP_SYS(lseek),
                                SCMP_SYS(clock_gettime), SCMP_SYS(pread64)}; // add extra rule for pread64

    int syscalls_whitelist_length = sizeof(syscalls_whitelist) / sizeof(int);
    scmp_filter_ctx ctx = NULL;

    ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_KILL);

    if (!ctx)
    {
        return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < syscalls_whitelist_length; i++)
    {
        if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, syscalls_whitelist[i], 0) != 0)
        {
            return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
        }
    }
    if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(execve), 1, SCMP_A0(SCMP_CMP_EQ, (scmp_datum_t)(_config->exe_path))) != 0)
    {
        return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
    }
    if (!allow_write_file)
    {
        if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(open), 1, SCMP_CMP(1, SCMP_CMP_MASKED_EQ, O_WRONLY | O_RDWR, 0)) != 0)
        {
            return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
        }
        if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(openat), 1, SCMP_CMP(2, SCMP_CMP_MASKED_EQ, O_WRONLY | O_RDWR, 0)) != 0)
        {
            return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(open), 0) != 0)
        {
            return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
        }
        if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(dup), 0) != 0)
        {
            return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
        }
        if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(dup2), 0) != 0)
        {
            return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
        }
        if (seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_ALLOW, SCMP_SYS(dup3), 0) != 0)
        {
            return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
        }
    }

    if (seccomp_load(ctx) != 0)
    {
        return LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED;
    }
    seccomp_release(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

`main.c`

> temp.c is a simple C file, temp is the C object file that I'm trying to execute in the project

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <seccomp.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "seccomp_rules.h"

int main()
{

    struct config _config;
    long orig_eax;
    _config.exe_path = "/home/ubuntu/runner/temp";
    _config.args[0] = _config.exe_path;
    _config.args[1] = NULL;
    _config.env[0] = "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";
    _config.env[1] = "LANG=en_US.UTF-8";
    _config.env[2] = "LANGUAGE=en_US:en";
    _config.env[3] = "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8";
    _config.env[4] = NULL;

    pid_t child_pid = fork();

    // pid < 0 shows clone failed
    if (child_pid < 0)
    {
        printf("FORK_FAILED");
    }
    else if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        c_cpp_seccomp_rules(&_config, true);
        execve(_config.exe_path, _config.args, _config.env);
        printf("execve failed\n");
    }
    else if (child_pid > 0)
    {
        
    }
}
```

`seccomp_rules.h`

```c
#ifndef SECCOMP_RULES_H
#define SECCOMP_RULES_H
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define LOAD_SECCOMP_FAILED -1;

struct config
{
    char *exe_path;
    char *args[20];
    char *env[20];
};

int c_cpp_seccomp_rules(struct config *_config, bool allow_write_file);

#endif // SECCOMP_RULES_H
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.5)
# set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE "STATIC_LIBRARY")
# SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
# SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
project(Seccomp)

#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-g -Wall -O3 -std=c99 -pie -fPIC")

file(GLOB SOURCE "./*.c")
add_executable(seccomp.so ${SOURCE})
target_link_libraries(seccomp.so pthread seccomp)


install(FILES output/seccomp.so
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_READ
    DESTINATION /usr/lib/runner)
```

Put all these files in a folder and execute these commands.

- `cmake . &&  make`
- `./output/seccomp.so`

Comment: There is a mess with file suffixes. `.o` does not belong to executable files, these are compiled objects that need to be linked. `so` is for dynamically loaded libraries. It is not *forbidden* to give your files unusual suffixes but will surely confuse everybody. Executable files do not need any suffixes. Your CMakeLists.txt is silent about your test program, how do you build it?

Comment: Oh! It didn't give me an error. But, I'll correct it. Do you know what is causing this and how to fix the problem?